# Different results from any(df.isnull()) and pd.isnull(data).any()

Tags: pandas, dataframe, missing-data, isnull

I am using the standard Boston houses data frame with pandas and I have noticed something that bugs me:

when I'm checking for missing values in 2 different ways - I'm getting 2 different results, though it shouldn't be.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Here's my code:

```
# loading df
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
boston=load_boston()
boston_data = pd.DataFrame(data=boston.data, columns=boston.feature_names)
boston_data['price']=boston.target # the price column
```

Now if I run this code:

```
pd.isnull(boston_data).any()
```

this is the outcome:

```
CRIM       False
ZN         False
INDUS      False
CHAS       False
NOX        False
RM         False
AGE        False
DIS        False
RAD        False
TAX        False
PTRATIO    False
B          False
LSTAT      False
dtype: bool
```

However, if I run it like this:

```
any(boston_data.isnull())
```

it returns: True

Why?..

Comment: What is returned by `boston_data.isnull()`?

Comment: a huuge df of booleans. it's a 506x13 df, hard to just eyeball it

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between the `.any()` function that comes with Pandas, and the builtin `any()` function that comes with Python. The Pandas `.any()`  will evaluate `bool(x)` for each x that is a value in the `Series`. So, if you call `df.isnull()`, you will create a boolean dataframe (lots of `True` and/or `False`). Calling Pandas' `.any()` function on that dataframe, will return `True` if any of the values in the boolean dataframe is `True`. In this case, none of the values are missing so this will return `False`.

Now, the builtin `any()` function takes an **iterable** and will apply `bool(x)` for each value in the provided **iterable**. If you provide a `pd.DataFrame` object to it, it will iterate over it. You can see what happens if you try to iterate over a `DataFrame` object like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6]})
print(df)
#    A  B
# 0  1  4
# 1  2  5
# 2  3  6
for x in df:
    print(f'x is of type {type(x)} and is of value {x}')
# x is of type <class 'str'> and is of value A
# x is of type <class 'str'> and is of value B
```

So, if you call the builtin `any()` function, you basically are saying
`any([bool('A'), bool('B')])`, which is the same as `any([True, True])` which is `True`.

Long story short: don't use builtin `any()` with Pandas, as the iteration on a dataframe might not yield what you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

`pd.isnull(boston_data).any()` checks for missing values across columns and returns False for all columns in your case

`any(boston_data.isnull())` checks for missing values across all columns and returns True because there is at least one missing value in DF

Comment: Yes that is the question; how can all columns have no empty values separately, but the df does have empty values?

Comment: @JarroVGIT @JarroVGIT At first, I thought this could be due to the presence of extremely small values in DF (<0.01), but even after replacing them with higher value, I still got the same. Currently, I don't have any idea why ```True``` appears. Do you have any thoughts about his? :)

Comment: Short answer: `any()` iterates over the dataframe (not its columns or its values or its rows), which yields column labels (which always evaluate to `True` -> `bool('A') == True`. The pandas `.any()` function takes all the values of the dataframe. So, don't use builtin Python's `any()` with dataframes.